# How to query my database to get the result as an array?

Tags: php, codeigniter, codeigniter-2

my database table structure is like following:

```
wdt        date            teacherid
1       2011-01-11           1001
2       2011-01-11           1002
3       2011-01-12           1001
4       2011-01-12           1002
```

Now what I want to do is select the date field from the table where teacherid="1001" and then return the result as an array like this- array("2011-01-11","2011-01-12")

so that in my view file I can check if a particular data exists in the array result-  like following :

```
 if (in_array("2011-05-18", $date))       // here the $date would be the array result which -
                                        //  I am expecting to get from model via controller
        {
        echo "Found"; 
        }
```

My controller looks like following:

```
function index(){


    $this->load->model('mod_teacher_workingday');
    $data['date']= $this->mod_teacher_workingday->get();

    $data['main_content']='view_teacher_workingday';
    $this->load->view('includes/template',$data);
  }
```

Would you please kindly show me how my model should look like in order to get the result as an array in my view file and I can check if a particular data exists in that array? Just for your information I am using Codeigniter.

Thanks :)

Comment: in_array could/should be replace with array_flip && isset

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Should be:

```
$query = $this->db->select('date')
                  ->from('teachers')
                  ->where('teacherid',1001)
                  ->get();
$dates = array();
foreach($query->result() as $date)
{
  $dates[] = $date->date;
}
return $dates;
```

The returned array will be just empty in case of no results found for that ID.

Comment: hi, thanks for your reply.. i have tried the way you mentioned but when I run the script I find an error in my view in "if (in_array("2011-05-18", $date))".... the message says "Message: in_array() [function.in-array]: Wrong datatype for second argument"

Comment: UHm, I cannot test it now, so please var_dump() or print_r() the returned array to see how it actually looks like

Comment: Thank you Damien Pirsy. I had to make a slight change and it is working exactly how i wanted.. :) check the edited part of  you code..:) Thanks man

Comment: lol, I was about to run here editing out the mistakes I just realized after trying the code!:) Sorry mate, it's late here, I must be tired..anyway, I'm glad you found it useful! cheers!

Answer (score 1):

Why don't you look for the date with mysql, much more efficient.

```
Select teacherid from teachers where date = "2011-05-18" AND teacherid = 1001
```

If you get 0 results, you know that that combination does not exist

Comment: Actually if I do like the way you mentioned I have to make 365 different queries as I am working with a calender. After fetching all the information from database.. in my view file I just want to check if a particular date exists in the array result. if exists then I ask a php script to check a checkbox. Thanks :)

Answer (score 0):

Do yourself a favour, download an IDE that has database support.  Netbeans lets you connect to a database through a JDBC driver.  You can do a raw query on the fly right inside your application.  Then once you have your query nailed, simply transfer it to Codeigniter Active record or whatever you are using or just use Active records raw query.